# Поиск и замена

Tags: php

Запрашиваю содержание страницы для вывода, но пути там все локальные, а замена почему то не работает, и кодировка в том числе . .  В чём проблема?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?
$addr = "http://m.odnoklassniki.ru/";  // адрес страницы
$begblock1 = "<html
"; // идентификатор начала блока
$begin = "<html"; // фрагмент HTML-кода до полезных данных
$end = "</html>"; // фрагмент HTML-кода после полезных данных

$text= file_get_contents($addr);
$str = str_replace("href\"","href\"http:\/\/m.odnoklassniki.ru\/",$text);

print $str;

?>
```

Comment: Что на что конкретно требуется заменить?

Comment: \" наверное нужно заменить в коде на =\" (знак равно в указании аргумента HTML).

Comment: @bazaev05, как выглядят символы в неправильной кодировке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

> `string iconv ( string $in_charset , string $out_charset , string $str )`
> Преобразует набор символов строки str из кодировки in_charset в out_charset.